# Wrapping the placeholder text in new line in input field

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to style the placeholder in such a way that it should break the line something like this:

```
Hello
John Doe

<input type="text" placeholder="Hello John Doe" class="input_style">
```

Tried many solution. Not working. I know this can be implemented by textarea and I don't want to use bootstrap either. But I want to specifically use input field, css or some jquery or javascript to do this. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't have 2 lines of text in an `input[type="text"]`. You can write your own placeholder library that can put 2 lines of text in a textarea. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/NgKjQm if that would work, I can submit as an answer

Comment: @MichaelCoker thank you so much for the pen. But I wanted to try only for the `input[type="text"]`

Comment: YOu're welcome, but you can't put 2 lines of text in a text input...

Comment: @MichaelCoker yeah I am trying to do a hack..like jeremy suggested thatuse positioned node with text over it that has your placeholder and use some JS to hide that text when the field has focus or has data in it. So trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible AFAIK. From the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute:

> The placeholder attribute represents a short hint (a word or short phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry when the control has no value. A hint could be a sample value or a brief description of the expected format. The attribute, if specified, must have a value that contains no "LF" (U+000A) or "CR" (U+000D) characters.

Comment: is their any other way?? I have read this spec. I mean some kind of hack?? with the script I mean some other approach??

Comment: I mean, you could make the input larger, use positioned node with text over it that has your placeholder and use some JS to hide that text when the field has focus or has data in it....